# Extract frame time from historic Velodyne PCAP

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a method to extract the collected POSIX time from each frame in a PCAP file (collected on VLP-16) and not the current wall time? Using rospy to examine the nodes' headers provides the current wall time in POSIX and not the time which the frame was recorded.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331773/extract-frame-time-from-historic-velodyne-pcap/) by [shaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/45208/shaky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution to extracting the acquisition time from a PCAP file acquired by a Velodyne VLP-16 LIDAR in an [older question](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/57) by changing the packet stamp time in the input.cc file within the velodyne_driver package. The follow steps were borrowed from the [older question](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/57), but I will place here as well.

To accomplish this, git clone [velodyne package](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) into the catkin_workspace/src

*/home/user/catkin_ws/src*

and navigated to

*/home/user/catkin_ws/src/velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/lib*

and changed the following line in the input.cc file (line 320 on mine)

- **FROM**:   pkt->stamp = ros::Time::now();
- **TO**:  pkt->stamp = ros::Time(header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec * 1000);

Then run catkin_make in */home/user/catkin_ws* (and, don't forget to source the /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash) and I printed the timestamps for each packet, which matched the acquired time.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [shaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/45208/shaky/) with karma: 26 on 2019-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0